# UITableView does not reload after data source merging with background NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

In my view controller I have a table view that uses a `NSFetchedesultsController` as the data source. And I have to load data from server using another `NSManagedContext` instance in a background thread. After merging the foreground context with the the background context I need reflect change in the table view so that I reset the `NSFetchedResultsController`(So that it will fetch again for the newly arrived data) and then reload the table view.

It's very strange that it seems my table view does not reload till a few seconds later(Sometimes much longer). And I am sure it's not because of the fetching because when I scroll the table view the new data appears instantly.

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned out to be a consequen of me not understanding where the notification call back function is called. I reload my table view in the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification call back function. When I check which thread it's on in this function I found out this runs on another thread other than main thread that I had assumed. So I use GCD to get back on the main thread and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

After getting data and create managed objects then you needs to save backgrond context imediately , these objects will be merge into parent context, you can double check any change made to parent context
[Context hasChange]  [context updatedObjects]
 [ context insertedobjects]
Objects saved is still in memory you need reset background context clear them out

Answer (score 0):

Save operation should be made on the private queue of the child context, so you dont have to listen to notification, nested blocks waiting until all thing done and refetch.